# Wordpress: Change URL route of page

Tags: php, wordpress, url, routes

I'm new with Wordpress and I was asked to make some changes to a website. I need to change the following page's route (if possible):

`/travels/poi`

To:

`/location/region/poi`

Where `travels` is a listing of POIs (Points Of Interest). Is something like this possible?

EDIT: `location/region/` is a page that lists my POIs

Answer (score 0):

**If travel is a custom post type**, then you can define a custom permalink for it.

Looking for the code where you register the travel custom post type, something like this:

```
register_post_type( 'travels', $args );
```

Alter the **rewrite** argument:

```
$args = array(
    // your ohter args
    'rewrite'               => array(
        'slug'                  => 'location/region',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    ),
    // some other args
);
```

After you made this changes, you have to [flush the rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) or the changes takes no effect. To do this, just go to Settings -> Permalinks in wp admin (you don't have to change anything).

Comment: Hmm... l see, but where do l add this? Do l add it in "functions.php" just like where l add my action/filter hooks? Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on how the custom post type is created. Maybe you use a plugin for this travel thing?

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin that includes listings for "travels", "cars", "jobs", "hotels" etc.

Comment: In this case it is difficult. We should not change plugin code, because changes will be overriden during the next plugin update. A clean solution is only possible, if the plugin prvides a filter hook to alter the custom post type arguments. But this is improbable.